# Hide navbar on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm not able to hide the navbar after the link is clicked. I'm using bootstrap 3. I have added the script that should work. I'm not able to find the error. Can someone go through this code. Please

```js
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
  $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo-inv.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#fff'">पBrand</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#aboutUs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> 
    About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> 
    Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pawn"></span> Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span> 
    Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to docs you have to put `collapse in` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse)

> .collapse hides content
>
> .collapsing is applied during transitions
>
> .collapse.in shows content

But this is not enough.

> I'm not able to hide the navbar after the link is clicked.

Would you like to hide **the whole navbar** or **the menu section which appears on small screen sizes**?

If you want the first one you have to put classes in `nav` tag and use different query in jquery

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide'); // hides menu on lower screens
    //$(".navbar").collapse('hide'); // hides the whole navbar
  });
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="collapse in navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo-inv.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#fff'">पBrand</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse in navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#aboutUs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> 
    About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> 
    Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pawn"></span> Awards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span> 
    Documents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> 
    About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-link" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> 
    Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"  href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pawn"></span> Awards</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in js

```
$(function () {

  $(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function() {
  $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
  $(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function (event) {
    $(event.target).focus();
  });
});
```